# How do I add a speed to my jquery mouse events

Tags: jquery, image, performance, background, mouseenter

I am new to js/jquery and could use a bit of help.  This is functioning how I want it to, but I would like to slow down the transition between images.  Any thoughts on how to add speed to this event?

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $('.image1').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css('background-image','url("images/image1.jpg")'); 
    });
    $('.image1').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css('background-image','url("images/image2.jpg")'); 
    });           
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add speed"? Do you want to delay the change? Transition the change? Please be as specific as you can.

Comment: speed or delay? - if it's delay you can do [something like this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/changing-background-image-with-animation) otherwise you probably want to preload the images to speed it up

Comment: What is the size of image1 and image2? If they are not loaded with the reste of the page (if they are not in the brwoser cache), your browser needs to load them and it could be quite long if they are heavy

Comment: If there isn't a function to slow down the activity from happening, you can always use the native javascript timeout function.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! I want to slow the transition down.  Currently it happens instantly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $('.image1').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this)..stop(true).animate({
           'background-image','url("images/image1.jpg")'
        }, 5000,);
    });
    $('.image1').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this)..stop(true).animate({
           'background-image','url("images/image2.jpg")'
        }, 5000,);
    });           
});
```

Added .stop(true) based on @AntonBoritskiy excellent suggestion.

Comment: With such long animation times it is better to stop animation, when you start the new one, like `$(this).stop(true).animate(...`.
Otherwise user will manage to start several animations by hovering and leaving the target.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t set a time for the css function. If you want to animate something you’ll have to use animate or one of the other built in functions like fadeIn, fadeOut, fadeTo, hide, show, slideDown, etc.

For example :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hover').hover(
        function(){
            // On Mouse On
            var background = $(this).attr('data-background');
            if ( !background ) { return; }
            $(this)
                .css('background','url(' + background + ')')
                .children('img')
                .fadeOut('fast');
        },
        function(){
            // On Mouse Off
            $(this)
                .children('img')
                .fadeIn('fast');
        }    
    );
});
```

For more details look at this:  http://jsfiddle.net/mattgoucher/6tpC4/4/

Answer (score 0):

If we are only speaking about performance without adding new functionality, then:

-consider merging two images into a sprite
-consider switching to only CSS state switching via `:hover` pseudo-class, like

```
.image1 {
    /* normal styles */
}
.image1:hover {
    /* hover styles */
}
```

You can read more about that approach [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/). 
It will give much faster transitions, which is even easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the images faster you should have two images and then display the top one when hover:

html

```
<img class="image1" src="images/image1.jpg"/>
<img id="topImage" class="image1 hide" src="images/image2.jpg"/>
```

js

```
$(".image1").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#topImage").removeClass("hide");
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $("#topImage").addClass("hide");
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/avZFq/)